# Sending email via aws ses

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I have 2 servers A & B and hosted in AWS and my app is built using nodejs.

I have the same copy of application running on both servers. Now from server `A` the email works but not from `B`.

I have a file called `emailconfig.json` which has `accesskeyId`, `secretAccessKey and region` which I call to load the config.

I think the same config can't be used in another server in AWS to send the email?

Code --

```
router.post('/sendmail', function(req, res, next) {
    // load aws config
    console.log("I am here 1");
    aws.config.loadFromPath('\emailconfig.json');
    console.log("I am here 2");
```

For some reason, I can't see the second log in server B but works in server A.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your IAM permissions the same on both servers? Are your firewall rules the same as well?

Comment: Not sure. I have to check. Though the server B is exact clone of A.

Answer (score 0):

I think you server B IAM permission is different from the server A. Because it creates separate IAM Roles for each EC2, you should specify the IAM role which has been used for server A as the IAM role of server B too.